# Accessing RequestContext from with my MembershipProvider

Tags: asp.net, membership-provider, requestcontext

Is there an easier/better way to access the RequestContext from within a custom Membership Provider than the following (and further, will this method even work):

```
private static RequestContext GetRequestContext()
    {
        HttpContextBase contextBase = 
            new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);

         return new RequestContext(
                     contextBase, 
                     RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(contextBase));
    }
```

Comment: Why do you do this? Can't you use `HttpContext.Current.Request`?

Comment: @Aliostad: It would appear that I can indeed - I don't know what I wasn't seeing that made me want to do it the hard way.  Post this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Aliostad mentioned: use `HttpContext.Current.Request` instead.  He wouldn't repost his comment as an answer, so ...